# Count how many times a value is referenced in a grid

Tags: java, lambda

I've got list of points: `List<Point> seedPoints`. Each `Point` contains `x` and `y` coordinates pointing to certain `double` value (let's call it `pointValue`). I would like to display how many times each `pointValue` is referenced in `seedPoints` list. To do so I've created following lambda expression:

```
seedPoints.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p ->  pointGrid.get(p.x, p.y)))
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .map(entry -> "value:" + entry.getKey() + "   count: " + entry.getValue().size())
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

The solution works fine, I get the following output:

```
value:0.0   count: 1
value:3.0   count: 2
value:4.0   count: 1
value:5.0   count: 4
value:6.0   count: 2
```

I don't find it very clean however. This solution requires two call to the `stream()` method (1st and 4th line of code), as `collect()` method is a terminal operation. Does anybody has any idea how could I improve my lambda expression?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no intermediate operation that groups items by key.

But in your example there are some changes that can make code more readable.

- Instead of collectiing to `Map<Double, List<Point>>` you could collect directly to `Map<Double, Long>`

  ```
  .collect(groupingBy(p ->  pointGrid.get(p.x, p.y), counting()))
  ```
- Instead of creating stream and performing output just use `forEach` on a map

  ```
  .forEach((value, count) -> System.out.println("value :" + value + " count: " + count);
  ```

So together it looks like

```
seedPoints.stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(p ->  pointGrid.get(p.x, p.y), counting()))
    .forEach((value, count) -> System.out.println("value :" + value + " count: " + count);
```